# ui-gmap-window does not work, but ui-gmap-windows does

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I'm running into issues using angular-google-maps. I simply want to attach a basic infoWindow to each marker on my map. I'm using `ui-gmap-markers` and placing a `ui-gmap-window` inside each marker directive. This does not work, no window appears. However, when changing this to use `ui-gmap-windows` it works perfectly. What am I missing here? Shouldn't I simply be able to use one `ui-gmap-window` within each `ui-gmap-markers` dirctive rather than the plural form?

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center='playerMap.center' zoom='playerMap.zoom'>
  <ui-gmap-markers
    models="playerMap.markersAddresses"
    coords="'self'"
    icon="'icon'"
    doCluster="playerMap.cluster"
    fit="true"
    options="'options'">
    <ui-gmap-window>
      <b>Address: {{location}}</b>
    </ui-gmap-window>
  </ui-gmap-markers>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems with your approach:

- ui-gmap-window shouldn't be inside ui-gmap-markers tag;
- when you click on the marker you should pass the model to the window;

Section "How do I only open one window at a time?" in the [Angular Google Maps FAQ](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/?JRwnVeTsM4n98QWm-oHQDw&ved=0CBMQFjAAOAo&usg=AFQjCNGZWf3yx7Vg-YGZEM9xiHCJLP3Oeg#!/faq) may help.